Re-rendering issue with PDFs in React
const [numPagesState, setNumPagesState] = useState(0);
const allCertificates = formik?.values?.certificate_file || [];

{allCertificates?.length > 0 &&
   allCertificates?.map((el) => {
     return (
       <>
         <div>
           <div className="d-flex justify-content-between edit-delete-section">
             <div className="course-completion">
               Course Completion Certificate
             </div>
             <div className="d-flex">
               <div
                 onClick={() => {
                   setSelectedPreview(el);
                   setOpenCertificateModal(true);
                 }}
               >
                 <Edit className="EditIcon cursor-pointer" />
               </div>
               <div
                 onClick={() => {
                   setDeleteCertificateModal(true);
                 }}
               >
                 <Delete className="delete-button cursor-pointer" />
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>

           <div className="document-preview-form" ref={resizeRef}>
             <Document
               file={el?.file_url || "/blank.pdf"}
               onLoadSuccess={({ numPages }) =>
                 setNumPagesState(numPages ?? 0)
               }
             >
               {Array?.apply(null, Array(numPagesState))
                 ?.map((x, i) => i + 1)
                 ?.map((page) => (
                   <Page
                     key={page}
                     width={width ? width : 1}
                     pageNumber={page}
                   />
                 ))}
             </Document>
           </div>
         </div>
       </>
     );
   })}

I am getting the error:

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I am expecting my PDF files to load one below the other, since I used the map method.

"Can someone please help me?" is completely unnecessary to explicitly put into the title of a question.  It is implicit in every question asked on Stack Overflow that you want someone to help you.

Review what you want to do for onLoadSuccess method of Document and don't use states unless necessary. Currently its Render -> state update -> re-render -> state Change ----, If you avoid this pattern, this won't happen.

Instead of useState try useRef as it avoid re-renders:
const numPagesState = useRef(0);
and then you can use the .current method to assign values:
numPagesState.current = numPages
